# How can I add up the sum of these scores for the final value?

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

This is my first block of code, my main class. I already have the question array and objects created, this is just to show you guys what I am trying to get done.

```
for(int i = 0; i<questionArray.length; i++)
{
  questionArray[i].askQuestion();
  questionArray[i].getAnswer();
  questionArray[i].checkAnswer();
}
```

These are my methods used in the loop above:

```
public void askQuestion()
{
   System.out.println(question);
   System.out.println("This question is worth " + pointValue + " point(s)");
   System.out.println("Please enter your answer: ");
}

public String getAnswer()
{
    return answer;
}

public boolean checkAnswer()
{
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  String UserAnswer = keyboard.nextLine();
  if (UserAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
  {
    System.out.println("congratulations you have earned " + pointValue + " point(s)\n");
    return true;
  }
  else 
  {
    System.out.println("sorry you did not get the answer correct");
    System.out.println("The correct answer is " + this.answer + "\n");
    return false;
  }
}
```

So as you can see this is a `TriviaGame` class, 
1.)I am trying to make two methods, one that is capable of displaying the pointValue(only when user answer == answer) after each question. 
2.)The second one is adding up each of the pointValue(again when answers are equal. A.k.a checkAnswer == true) when the user gets the answer correct, and display all the results at the end.

Answer (score 2):

did you mean:

```
 int score += pointValue; // note the plus (+)
```

As an aside, consider changing `if (checkAnswer() == true)` to `if (checkAnswer())`

Answer (score 1):

In your first block of code, where you run each method within the for loop, you should run `questionArray[i].updateScore()` instead of `questionArray[i].checkAnswer()` . As of right now, you are running `checkAnswer()` which gets an answer from the user and checks to see whether it is correct. But if you plan to call `updateScore()` after this, I believe you will end up running `checkAnswer()` again within the condition of the if statement, thus collecting an answer from the user again without meaning to. By running just `updateScore()` , you will both gather the answer AND update the score. I'm not sure if you knew this already, but I thought I'd let you know just in case.

As for your initial question, you could try this:
    Create an boolean instance variable for your Question class (initialized to false) that will be set to true if their answer was correct. This way, you can iterate through your `questionArray` and just check to see whether their answer was correct or not. If it was answered correctly, then add the Question's `pointValue` to your total score.

I hope I understood your question and I hope this helps,
     Tyler

Comment: Every time i use updateScore, i have to hit enter after each question is answered, even if i do as you suggested. the program runs smooth without any updateScore method... but i still need to find a way to track the score, the way i have it set up is not working, is my checkAnswer() method wrong?

Comment: You could have a variable in your driver class to keep track of the running total (suppose it is declared      int total = 0;     Then, have your checkAnswer() method return an int (namely, the point value of the question if it is answered correctly, and 0 if it is not) instead of a Boolean. So then, inside of your for loop, you would say something like       total += questionArray[i].checkAnswer()     in place of the checkAnswer() line. This way, you could display and updated total after each question, and you would only have to iterate over the questionArray once

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and simplest way to do this is to just use a instance or static variable to keep track of it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use the variable `score` to aggregate the points earned so far? Then you have to make it an attribute of the class or declare it as static, should initialize it with 0 and, in fact, have to add the score earned each time, as Bohemian already told you.

```
int score = pointValue;
```

as well as

```
int score += pointValue;
```

is local to your updateScore method and it's value will be lost when the method is left. If you declare

```
static int score = 0;
```

Rgds,

Thomas